# What is the meaning of {' ~ '} in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Would someone be able to help me with an explanation of {' ~ '} in the below context for this jsx file?
My file: Post.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import User from './User';
import Timestamp from './Timestamp.jsx';

const Post = ({ user, title, text, category, created, updated }) =>
    <span>
        <b>{title}</b>: {text}
        <i>{' ~ '}<User {...user} /></i><br />
        (Created at: <Timestamp data={created} />, Updated at: <Timestamp data={updated} />)
    </span>

export default Post
```

Comment: No different to `{'  '}`  but instead of a car, it's a squiggly tilde symbol.  It's done this way as SPACE in HTML generally has no meaning.   So the coder wanted space tilde space.

Answer (score 0):

That's a string literal. It's literally just rendering the string ' ~ ' in the output.

Answer (score 0):

In JSX, the syntax {' ~ '} is simply a representation of a string containing a tilde (~) surrounded by curly braces to render it within the JSX code.

In JSX, anything enclosed within curly braces { } is treated as JavaScript expression or code. So, {' ~ '} is a way to include the string with the tilde as part of the JSX code.

For example:

```
<div>
  Some text{' ~ '}Some more text
</div>
```

This would render as:

```
Some text ~ Some more text
```

It's a way to insert specific strings or characters into the JSX content directly while keeping them separate from surrounding text or JSX elements.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, {' ~ '} is used to insert a tilde (~) character into the string. It's a way to include a specific character as part of the text in JSX, separating the title of the post from the user's information for better visual clarity.

For example:

```
<div>
<b>Title</b>: Some text <i>{' ~ '}User Info</i>
</div>
```

This renders as:

Title: Some text * ~ *User Info